# how to lay cables onto a mesh and cut the cables in a specific way

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, conversion

i am making a model, my goal with the model was to replace his inner body into a span of cables like you would see in si-fi movies, or maybe games like fnaf so that the inner body even though replaced, the cables have the same proportions as the inner body[image], i tried to make a Bezier curve, then shrink-wrap it to the model then convert to mesh,[image] [image] [image] however that's extremely time consuming, and when I convert to mesh, the cable has too many vertices, along with this the model in question is for a game that I will be working on, I need a certain amount of vertices, this and when I try to reduce the amounts of vertices, the cables look off and not what I want, I need it to lay on top of the model, but his entire body is made of wires in certain directions for his body, arms, legs, head, if anyone could help me with this I would be most grateful,

also if you cant answer this part its fine, I would like to know if I would be able to cut the wires in a way that his eyes would show, and his mouth would show, without ruining the flow of that specific set of wires[image]

this is a small reference drawing to just show what i mean when i want the wires to form a body
[image]

Comment: sure thing, also the little pat at the end was related to the ret of the question as parts of the mesh have holes and need cables to be removed, thanks for informtion, i will add some drawing of what i want it to be like, thank you

Comment: what about normal maps?

Comment: could you explain about what you mean with normal maps??

Comment: yeah actually yes, but more organised to give it more of a brand new feel, not clumped together like ennard, but yes i believe something like that is what i am inspired to make

Comment: you could do it for real with cables that you make with cylinder that has array + curve modifiers, put the cables all over the body, then bake the normals so that you'll be able to fake the cables on the surface of the body and maybe just keep only several of real cables

Comment: ooh that sounds pretty interesting, is there any videos that could explain what you mean, i like the sound of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a cylinder along a curve with the *Array* and *Curve* modifiers (1), duplicate the body to keep a low poly somewhere, put the pipes on the body, apply the modifiers, merge the pipes with the body (2), create a new material for the low-poly object, create an *Image Texture* node and a new image (*32 Bit float*) in this *Image Texture*, bake the normal of the high-poly to the low-poly, plug the normal map into a *Normal* map and plug the *Normal* map into the *Normal* socket of the *Principled BSDF* in order to see the fake 3D (3):

[image]

Comment: you have no heart!!! What did you do to suzanne!?  +1 because i think you did it not on purpose.....!

Comment: I saved her life! Now she's Cybersuzanne! By the way I have a bug with snapping the curve to the surface, I don't understand why...

Comment: that's because you give so much pain to suzanne... i didn't even know that you can snap a curve to surface....‍♂️

Comment: actually it looks like if I use the curve as the Curve Object of my object it can't snap, weird, so the solution might be to first snap the curves, then use them for the pipe mesh

Comment: or you convert it to mesh...and then snap ;)

Comment: i understand how it works now, i just need to know, is there a youtube video that could break down step by the step how it works in detail, i love your answer and think its the best choice

Comment: @ Chris, if I convert to mesh I can't use it as Curve Object, but I can simply deactivate the visibility of the Curve modifier and it works

Comment: @JustImpact you need to find tutos about Array and Curve modifiers for a mesh, then snap the curves to the object (disable the Curve modifiers visibility otherwise it doesn't seem to work), then look into baking normals tutos

Comment: @ Chris actually it depends on the shape of the tube, if it's a simple pipe you can use an edge that you extrude then a Skin modifier + Subdivision Surface

Comment: hey when you did what you did in the picture why are there spaces, i just want to know if you added spaces or does it automatically do that

Comment: you mean space between cables? It's because there were spaces between my 3D cables so it baked space